# Creating Linux Alias to list only Directories

Tags: linux, tabs, alias, multiple-columns, ksh

I'm wanting to create an alias called `dir` for KSH that will show only the sub-directories in a cluttered directory with many files and directories.

I can output a single-column list of the directories, but I am having a problem converting the single-column list into a multi-column.

I want it to automatically determine the number of columns to use based on the length of the longest string and the width of the terminal window in the same way that the `ls` command automatically creates tabbed columns.

Say I type the following at the terminal to give me a list of all the directories in the current directory:

```
ls -1Fa | grep /
```

When I pipe this output to `column -t`, it doesn't seem to have any effect... I get a list of 54 directories in a single column.  I've also tried the common suggestion in other posts of piping to `column -t -s $'\t'` or `column -t -s $'\n'`, but it always results in a single list output. I've looked at the man pages and tried all the options, but I cannot get it to produce output similar to `ls`.

I've also tried piping the output to pr with the following:

```
alias dir="ls -1Fa | grep / | pr -T -w $COLUMNS -6"
```

Unfortunately, this will always output 6 columns and if the terminal window is rather skinny (i.e. $COLUMNS is something small like 50) then long directory names are truncated at the beginning of the next column.

Can somebody answer why `column` is not outputting the list into columns, or does somebody have a better solution using another tool such as sed, awk, perl?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, all you need is

```
alias dir='ls -d */ .*/'
```

The trailing slash instructs ksh to only include directories in the glob expansion. And you get to piggy-back on how `ls` formats into columns.

The answer to your question is that you're using the wrong option for `column`:

```
ls -1d */ .*/ | column -c $(tput cols)
```

`column -t` pretty-prints the output, from

```
1
a b
foobar baz
```

into

```
1
a       b
foobar  baz
```

See the [`column` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/column.1.html)

Comment: Thanks @glenn! I knew about the `-d` switch in the man pages, but didn't see anything about needing to include a string pattern. Why is this? You don't need them when you do a normal `ls` to list the directory contents, including sub-directories, so why here? Also, thanks for the explanation about the `-t` and `-c` switches with `column`. I had tried using `-c` but wasn't getting any success b/c I never used a column size >50. The explanation for that switch is also a little confusing. I interpreted "_formatted for a display **columns** wide_" as how many tabbed columns I wanted for the output

Comment: When you do a plain `ls`, you are effectively descending into the current directory. Compare the difference with plain `ls -d`

Comment: I think your explanation may have gone a little over my head. When I type plain `ls -d`, it only outputs the current directory (or `.`). If you're implying that it outputs the current directory because that is my current path & therefore I've already descended into it, & that you must tell it to descend into the other subdirectories using glob expansion patterns in order to show those directories in the output, then it still confuses me why the default behavior of plain `ls -d` doesn't imitate the behavior of plain `ls`. Where would you need plain `ls -d`? Why not make it work like plain `ls`?

Comment: If you want to look at the long listing of a sub-directory and not the contents of the subdirctory, you would do `ls -l -d ./subdir`

Comment: Note that for `ls *`, the wildcard is expanded *first* before `ls` is executed, so you get `ls file1 file2 dir1 file3 ...`, and that will list the contents of the subdirectories. If you don't want that, and in your question I think you don't, add `-d`

Comment: So really glob expansion does all the work. `ls -d */ .*/` could be replaced by `echo */ .*/` or `echo */ .*/ | tr ' ' '\n'` (if I want output separated by newlines). `ls -d` is just echoing the shell's glob expansion. It seems to me that `ls -d` should assume `* .*` if no arguments are supplied the same way that `ls` by itself lists all the files &all the subdirs of the current dir if no arguments are supplied. `ls` is supposed to be the list command but when `-d` is supplied, it doesn't produce a list unless you supply it in the arguments (either explicitly or implicitly with glob expansion)

Comment: No, `ls` uses `.` as the default if no files are provided. Therefore `ls -d` does too. If you want the behaviour you specify, you can write a short function for it.

Comment: Also `echo * | tr ' ' '\n'` is *not* the same as `ls` -- `ls` will properly handle files with spaces in the name and the `echo | tr` pipeline will not.